# kotlin how do i make a function for that?

Tags: image, kotlin

I have this screen, I need appropriate text for each r.drawable that is seen in random mode, in each imageview, I wrote the app in KOTLIN and I'm almost done, I just need this text resource explaining the displayed image , to each image its text, can you help me? thank you

I don't know how to create a text that changes according to the image

```
private lateinit var listId: List<Int>


 private fun pickNumber (){
        val (id1, id2, id3) = listId.shuffled()
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(id1)
        binding.imageView2.setImageResource(id2)
        binding.imageView3.setImageResource(id3)
        
        private fun initializeList() {
        listId = listOf(
            R.drawable.r02 ,
            R.drawable.w02s,
            R.drawable.ror,
            R.drawable.rands,
            R.drawable.rups,
            R.drawable.rles,
            R.drawable.rsw)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to link each text resource to appropriate image resourse is to change type of `listId` variable from `List<Int>` to `Map<Int, Int>`. Now it will contain pairs of image resources and text resources. Also you should change `listOf(...)` method to `mapOf(R.drawable.desired_drawable to R.string.desired_text, ...)` and `listId.shuffled()` to `listId.toList().shuffled()`. After this you can just operate with gained pairs of values to set them to corresponding views.

Comment: Instead of `listId.map { it.key to it.value }` you can just write `listId.toList()`.

Comment: I am trying but it gives me error on string when I write in the map list, if you hope give me some help again

Comment: Thanks, @KarstenGabriel, I just updated my answer. Didn't notice that I could do it more simple

Comment: I can't even set the text in a textview created specifically to host the text in the list with map function with r.drawable.immage to r.string.one

Comment: @ekio87 could you please get more details when it happens with code examples

Comment: @RomanPopov     private fun initializeList() {
        listId = mapOf(
            R.drawable.rw02cups to R.string.tre_di_coppe, <----string.tre_di_coppe error

Comment: @RomanPopov    private fun pickCard (){
        val (id1, id2, id3) = listId.toList().shuffled()
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(id1)
        binding.textnamecard.toString(id1) <--- id1 error

Comment: @ekio87, to solve "id1" error just use `.first` or `.second` on it (don't forget it's a pair of values, not just one). And I don't quite understand what's wrong in your first code sample, could you send error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245433/discussion-between-roman-popov-and-ekio87).